# React-Select being rendered before options can populate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-select

I'm using `react-select` found here: https://react-select.com/home#welcome

My dropdown is currently empty and I believe the select element is getting rendered before the setState happens. I see in the documentation that they have `async` component but not sure how to convert my code to fix this issue.

Here is my code:

```
async GetFlavors() {
    let preprocessedData;
    try {
        let getFlavors1 = [
            { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
            { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
            { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
            ]

        console.log(getFlavors1);

            this.setState({ getFlavors: [...getFlavors1] });    
            console.log(this.state.getFlavors); 

    } catch(error) {

    }

    return preprocessedData;

}

async componentDidMount() {
    await this.GetFlavors();
}

<label className="form-label">
    Flavors:
</label>
<Select
    value={this.state.flavors}
    onChange={this.handleChangeFlavors}
    options={this.state.getFlavors}
/>
```

Comment: What part of the documentation or AsyncSelect examples do you need help with?

Comment: @DrewReese I'm not even sure if I need to use AsyncSelect. But right now my dropdown the `options={this.state.getFlavors}` it's empty, but I know there are items in the `this.state.getFlavors` I just think it's being rendered before it get's set

Comment: That is *usually* ok as the component will rerender again when the state updates. An issue may be that `Select` may not reset options upon subsequent rerenders, and thus probably the need for the async select. I'm not familiar with either though.

Comment: Think you could create a simple *running* codesandbox with this code and options for us to live debug in?

Answer (score 0):

The first `render()` occurs *before* `componentDidMount` runs. You can confirm this by doing a search for `react component lifecycle`.

The solution is to check for the presence of data before rendering any components that use it. This can be done in various ways, here I'm doing it as `{data && <Component>}`:

```
{this.state.getFlavors &&
    <Select
        value={this.state.flavors}
        onChange={this.handleChangeFlavors}
        options={this.state.getFlavors}
    />
}
```

Also a note: I am not sure if `componentDidMount` can be used with an `async` prefix. A solution to use a Promise inside `componentDidMount` typically looks like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("your url")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => this.setState({ data: json }));
}
```

Comment: this is an excellent approach but when I do that now that Select doesn't even load

Comment: That is correct, and I even consider it intentional because the `Select` can't be used anyway until it has options. As soon as the `state` is updated with the requested data (which should happen rather quickly), `render()` will be executed again (by React, automatically) showing the `Select` with the options that it now has.

Comment: Furthermore, I added an async note to my answer, this could be the change that you need to make.

Comment: try doing this.
componentDidMount = async () => {}